# Double properties will not be serialized to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, double

We serialize an object to xml:

```
   public class Test: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public virtual string Name {get; set;}
       public virtual double TestScore {get; set;}
   }
```

Using following method:

```
public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this object obj)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
            return XElement.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

In the following context (code is running in x64 context, a .net library is called from within C++ library):

```
XDocument rootElement = ...

Test test = new Test();
test.Name = "xxx";
test.TestScore= 1.0d;
rootElement.Add(test.ToXElement());
```

All properties of type (string, bool, long, int, ushort etc) are serialized except for double properties. They will be serialized once they manually converted to something else (not double).

Xml looks like this:

```
<Root>
  <Test>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
  </Test>
</Root>
```

Is there any reason why double properties are not serialized?

Comment: How do you know that double aren't serialize ? Can you provide the output ?

Comment: When I run this code (except just capturing the returned `XElement` in a variable since I don't have a `rootElement`), the element contains both the Name and the TestScore.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am expecting too, unfortunately in our set (project, platform etc) double properties are not serialized.

Comment: *You* need to debug this. We know that, if we place all of the above code in a fresh project, it works as expected. So do that, then start adding more aspects of your actual solution until it breaks.

Comment: Is this the exact class you are trying to use, or do you have derived types, explicit Interface implementations a.s.o.?
Especially Explicit Interface implementations are not public and can therefore not be serialized.

Answer (score 4):

To define how precise you want to serialize it, you should make it manually.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public double Price { get;set; }

[XmlElement("Price")]
public string PriceString {
    get {return Price.ToString();}
    set {Price = double.Parse(value);}
}
```

from http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/768555-serializable-double-precision

Comment: Thanks, we have tried this as well and it works, as a temporary workaround we are manually serializing the object. The problem is not that we do not get the right precision, but that we don't get the property at all (maybe ToString() fails inside the serialization engine). I would very much like to know the reason for this strange behavior.